# How to hide windows in VisionOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui, visionos

I'm developing an app for VisionOS using Swift/SwiftUI. A core piece of the functionality is to allow users to pin/anchor different windows around their environment.

I want to make it so walls and physical object block the windows. For example, if they leave the room, they will no longer see the windows until they walk back. Is there a way to make this possible, where the user can anchor the window and have walls block its visibility? I can't find anything reading through Apple's documentation, and it's such a new product that there isn't a lot of content regarding app development for VisionOS online.

I've tried reading through Apple's documentation, and I checked the settings in VisionOS to see if there was an option to hide windows with physical objects such as walls, but I didn't find anything. I am only using the simulator, so this may be a limiting factor.

In terms of pinning/anchoring the windows, when I place a window in the simulator, it seems like it moves a little bit as I walk around.